# Screenshot application for RHEL6.5

Tags: linux, screenshot, rhel6

I need some screen capture application for RHEL6.5 and tried few ways to get one but failed.

1. `yum install gnemo-utils` and got:

   Reading Local RPMDB
    rpmdb time: 0.000
    Setting up Install Process
    Checking for virtual provide or file-provide for gnome-utils
    No package gnome-utils available.
    Error: Nothing to do

Q: Is there a repo or some other way to get it installed?

2. `yum install shutter`

   ```
   Error: Package: shutter-0.93-1.el6.nux.noarch (nux-dextop)
      Requires: perl(JSON)
   Error: Package: perl-Net-OAuth-0.28-1.el6.noarch (epel)
      Requires: perl(Digest::SHA)
   Error: Package: shutter-0.93-1.el6.nux.noarch (nux-dextop)
      Requires: perl(Time::HiRes)
   Error: Package: perl-Net-DBus-0.33.6-8.el6.x86_64 (epel)
      Requires: perl(Time::HiRes)
   Error: Package: perl-HTTP-Server-Simple-0.43-1.el6.rf.noarch (rpmforge)
      Requires: perl(CGI)
   Error: Package: perl-Gtk2-1.248-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
      Requires: perl(HTML::TreeBuilder)
   ..... more errors related to `perl`
   ```

Trying to get `perl`:

```
  COMMAND: yum install perl 
  Installroot: /
  Ext Commands:

     perl
  Setting up Package Sacks
  Running "exclude" handler for "security" plugin
  pkgsack time: 0.060
  Reading Local RPMDB
  rpmdb time: 0.000
  Setting up Install Process
  Checking for virtual provide or file-provide for perl
  Nothing to do
```

Q: How it can be resolved?

3. `Print Screen` shortcut is complaining for `gnome-screenshot` not found.

Q: How it can be installed?

Ultimately, I just need some application to get screenshots.

Regards,

Comment: Any reason why you , whoever that might be, take points away? Is not like I care...just curious what was your logic. I did my `homework` for 2 days before posting but could not get it work. Isn't this a a place where people suppose to ask for help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `yum install gnome-utils`.

You can find which package provides a particular command as follows:

```
# yum provides \*gnome-screenshot
[...]
1:gnome-utils-2.28.1-10.el6.x86_64 : GNOME utility programs
Repo        : base
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/share/gnome-screenshot
Filename    : /usr/bin/gnome-screenshot
```

Comment: `  *gnome-screenshot
Setting up Package Sacks
Running "exclude" handler for "security" plugin
pkgsack time: 0.060
Reading Local RPMDB
rpmdb time: 0.000
Searching 0 packages
No Matches found`

Answer (score 1):

I had a 3rd party repo added in  but the machine has been  re-register with RHN afterwards.
I had to remove the 3-rd party repos and register the machine again.